# Android ADB drivers installation error

Tags: usb, adb

I am trying to install the usb adb drivers. I turned the `debugging mode` on in the settings of my phone, connected to the PC. I click update drivers and manually selected the folder where the drivers are placed. For some reason the drivers installation fails and Windows gives the following error. Kindly guide me what is going on and how can I solve this issue? I am on windows 7

**Drivers Installation error**

[image: Driver Installation Error]
<sup>(click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Try generic usb drivers, as koush adb drivers. That helped

Answer (score 1):

**It sounds like your drivers are fine**
Are you trying to use ADB with the Android SDK or are you using it for running commands etc...

If you are using ADB to run commands and ADB isn't installed as a recognized command ( universal installation )

then you'll need to run `adb` in it's directory.

Unzipping [Easy ADB V1.zip](https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=16StvqpL66mJ6uVBqYjquR6k9RXS58uBR&export=download) will give you a few versions.

- Auto Authentication ADB - Used for automatically asking for
  authentication.
- Normal ADB - Old device's  ... new device's will say Offline without
  the authentication.
- Fastboot
- OPEN ME.bat

Double click on Open Me.bat to start a command window using the desired option, this is a simple batch menu to start a command window in the desired directory, right click and edit it to customize the colors etc....

Make sure your device is recognized as Android Composite Device etc....

And run `adb devices` from the command window you opened.

> If you've chosen the Auto Authentication version, you'll need to accept the connection on your device.

Sometimes you will need to do this on the normal version as well. ( it's just an old version )

Hope this all helps simplify the process ...

**Using the SDK** 
You should only download the entire Software Development Kit if you actually plan on developing software...

It should automatically use the correct directory in Android Studio, without modifications.

I personally use the Easy ADB files - I just slapped the .BAT file together to make easier for beginners to navigate without using `cd`.

Answer (score 0):

If it is showing the Android Composite ADB Interface, then the driver should already be installed.

What happens if you type the below in the window's command prompt? It should show your device and serial number (assuming the phone is hooked up with USB Debugging enabled, and you are either running adb from the directory it is located in, or it is located within window's preset PATH variable).

`adb devices`

Comment: No it is not installed because windows automatically installed these drivers I don't know from where. So When I uninstall them and click update drivers and manually browse to the folder where the drivers are present, it still gives me errors. I have updated the question

Comment: Windows says, `adb is not recognized as internal or external command `

Comment: what should I do now?

Comment: You need to have adb on your computer (you can get standalone packages or install the Android SDK). Most likely, you won't have the location setup in your path, so you would have to manually navigate to the directory where adb is installed with the command line. And the drivers shouldn't need to be uninstalled/reinstalled if the computer already properly recognizes the device (which it seems it does).

Answer (score 0):

Without having the Android SDK/Android Development tools(ADT) environment it would be useless to have the ADB USB driver as matter of the fact that the ADB USB drivers are used to connect to Android Devices only through the ADB interface for development/debugging/root purpose .

So as @bass has rightly said about the Android SDK you need to have it installed from this [Android developer site](http://developer.android.com).

After you download the SDK you need to install the USB packages from the SDK manager(if you are connecting nexus)/from the OEM site(clueless about which Make or device number you are trying to connect and different OEM have their own Debug driver's) for the Debug USB Drivers.

Comment: You don't need a massive software development kit for three files..

Answer (score 0):

Try "Search Automatically for updated driver software" instead of browsing manually. This will check for your connected phone driver online!

Answer (score 0):

Download ADB drivers from [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?2tunwdxr3q2q8ec). Extract somewhere. Now, go to Device Manager and select your ADB device. Update Driver Software > Search your Computer > Browse to the folder you extracted and let it install.

Comment: That sounds like the steps the questioner already took to get to the error they saw.

Comment: Not sure though if he downloaded the same package as the link above. I had problems with different packages on ADB before.

Comment: Downloading drivers from a random Mediafire share is certainly a good way to have problems. It's better to stick with an official source, or failing that, a trusted third party such as Koush's drivers.